# Cookies created in JSP page are not available in Servlet, only the JSESSIONID cookie is available

Tags: jsp, servlets, cookies

I have created a JSP page which creates two cookies and adds it to response object. This page having a submit button which calls a servlet object. And this servlet will try to access cookies stored by the prior JSP page, but it is only able to access JSESSIONID cookie. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This will happen when you haven't explicitly set the cookie path. It will then default to the current folder in the request URI. Browser will only send the cookie back when cookie's path matches the current request URI.

So, imagine that your JSP has the URI `/pages/some.jsp`, then any cookie created in the JSP will have a default path of `/pages`. This means that the browser will only send the cookie back on any request matching `/pages/*`. If your servlet has the URI `/someServlet`, then it won't retrieve the cookie. It will only retrieve cookies having path `/someServlet` or `/`.

If you want to make your cookie applicationwide, then you need to explicitly set the path to `/`.

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, value);
cookie.setPath("/");
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

This will then also be available in in any servlet or JSP running on a different (sub)folder.